# preventing spam comments

Tags: spam-prevention

I have a page where logged users can post comments. I want to stop users to post the comments simultaneously to prevent the spam. For that purpose, I want a gap of 30 seconds between the comments (should i store the time in session ?), also if the user posts 10 comments in given 5 minutes, reCaptcha should be enabled (and reset the comment counter in session). Is this approach ok?

Answer (score 1):

Session might be good idea. However, I think many bots are not allowing cookies, and therefore sessions are not followed.

Posting 10 successful comments is enough for most spammers - after that reCaptcha is just annoyance for active normal users.

I strongly recommend trying [Akismet](http://akismet.com/). It's unbelievable good for comment spam.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think the answer to all those SPAM comments is: FLASH comment box
I mean captcha is simply annoying... I would never leave a comment there where you have to have this captcha thingie going.
I would suggest something like: [flexi comments](http://flexicommentbox.alimsyed.com/) or something...

Comment: **No**. Flash is far *far* less convenient for many users than a captcha. Do **not** use a flash comment box unless you *really* dislike your users.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that you use the [rel="nofollow"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow) attribute on any html anchor tags that you allow end users to submit themselves in order to make spamming less attractive. rel="nofollow" tells search engines to ignore the link, and therefore doesn't allow the spammer to harvest e.g. google page rank from spam comment links on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a "last posted" time, and number in the last 5 minutes shouldnt be such a bad idea, as if you can only post every 30 seconds, 10 minutes is only a maximum 20 posts away. You could indeed store that as part of the session, as the data is retrievable from the database on login anyway (in case of session break down)